# Primitive type as data structure for API Blueprint

Tags: data-structures, apiblueprint, aglio, mson

I want to use primitive type for describe data structure. Like so:

```
# Data Structures

## Video Delete (enum[number])
+ `0` - Successful deletion.
+ `1` - Error occured.
```

And the output is.

```
{
    "enum": [
        1,
        0
    ],
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
}
```

So description is missing. I've tried to put description in different places. I did a lot of things (do not wanna talk about them). Also I've tried to add info to enum values like so:

```
+ `0` (number) - Successful deletion.
```

I do not know whether this problem deals with MSON syntax or Aglio generator.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax above is supported by MSON as far as I can tell. The problem is that Aglio doesn't do anything with the description, and when I went to look into adding it I realized that it isn't really supported in JSON Schema. There seem to be two methods people use to get around that fact:

1. Add the enumerated value descriptions to the main description, the Olio theme 1.6.2 has support for this but the C++ parser seems to still have some bugs around this feature:

   `## Video Delete (enum[number]) - 0 for success, 1 for error`
2. Use a weird `oneOf` syntax where you create sets of single enums with a description. I don't recommend this.

Unfortunately the first option requires work on your part and can't easily be done in Aglio. Does anyone else have a better description and some samples of MSON input -> JSON Schema output?